# How would I use limit comparison test on this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I go about using the limit comparison test on this series. I'm just not sure what value of 'bn' I would start with.. $$\sum_{n\geq1 }\frac{n!}{e^{n^{2}}}$$

Comment: I would rather use the Root Test. Ratio Test is good too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use limit comparison, this is a way. By Stirling's approximation we have$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}}=1$$
 so we have$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{e^{n^{2}}}\frac{e^{n^{2}+n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}}=1$$
 so we have to study$$\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^{n^{2}+n}}$$
 now note$$e^{n^{2}+n}\geq n^{2n+1/2}$$
 (you can take logs to see it), then$$\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^{n^{2}+n}}\leq\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{n}}<\infty.$$